# How can apply the same CSS rules to different selectors of this type?

Tags: css, css-selectors

in my web I have lots of elements of this type:

#CardLink-template--19499588518220__product-grid-8681116401996

There are structured in a grid, so there aren't direct brothers

My question is: Exists any way to apply the same rules to the different elements that share the root of the selector but change the final number?

Sorry for my bad english and thank you!

I tried to use some characters such as ">" , "," , "~", but I don't understand the hierarchy of this type of selectors.